# Html5: Video tag change video time display from MM:SS to HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Reg: HTML5 video tag:

May I know, is it possible to change video time display on the video from **MM:SS** to **HH:MM:SS**. For instance, screenshot as follows:

[image]

Comment: Sure. Just implement your own controls including time display

Comment: I need to change display time on the video..Could you please share official links ?

Comment: Start from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement).

Comment: I didn't find the property of my need (changing time display on the video)

Comment: You got it wrong. You have to output the time yourself. Just create/append a block under your video and output there the current time which may be read by respective property of video element.

Comment: Just to understand, do you think is your above solution feasible ?

Answer (score 2):

The time remaining is part of the user agent created shadow DOM, so we do not have access to it in order to change its content.

You could mash together something hackish as this (conceptual only! don't use for public/production):

```js
// NOTE: This is just a hack for webkit. A lot must be implemented here
// for realworld scenario, but don't use hacks like this for production/public.
// Need to detect webkit browser. If layout changes, each version must be tracked etc.
// Build a custom player instead...
var v = document.querySelector("video");
var time = document.querySelector(".time");

v.onplay = v.oncanplay = function() {
  var dur = this.duration;
  time.innerHTML = "/ " + pad2((dur / 3600) | 0) + 
                    ":" + pad2((dur / 60) | 0) + 
                    ":" + pad2((dur % 60) | 0);
};

function pad2(s) {return s < 10 ? "0" + s : s}
```

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
  color: #fff;
  width: 55px;
}

.wrapper {position: relative}

.wrapper > video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper > .time {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  top: 177.5px;
  color: #777;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <video id="v" controls src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"></video>
  <div class=time>/ 00:00:00</div>
</div>
```

but the better approach is to create custom controls, or use something like [videojs](http://videojs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
secs = Math.round(secs);
var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

var obj = {
    "h": hours,
    "m": minutes,
    "s": seconds
};
return obj;
}
```

Comment: I need to change display time on the video. It seems, your code is outside the video conversion.